# Models with two hasOne relations to same table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm building an MMA (mixed martial arts) website with CakePHP. I've got a `fights` table in my database that has three columns at its simplest: `id`, `fighter_a`, and `fighter_b`.

I'm having trouble getting my head around what type of relation my `Fight` model would have with my `Fighter` module. Am I right in thinking `fighter_a` and `fighter_b` would be two `hasOne` relations?

I tried this with the following in my `Fight` model:

```
<?php
class Fight extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Fight';
    public $hasOne = array(
        'FighterA' => array(
            'className' => 'Fighter',
            'foreignKey' => 'fighter_a'
        ),
        'FighterB' => array(
            'className' => 'Fighter',
            'foreignKey' => 'fighter_b'
        )
    );
}
```

And then this in my `Fighter` model:

```
<?php
class Fighter extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Fighter';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Fight'
    );
}
```

But this threw an error in my CakePHP application when calling `$this->Fight->findById($id)` (where `$id` was the ID of a fighter):

> **Error:** SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Fight.fighter_id' in 'field list'

How can I link my models so that I can call all fights a fighter has been in?

Comment: Does your app show the SQL debug? If so, could you please copy the relevant query to your question?

It might be that you need to define your hasMany's as homeFight and awayFight depending on whether the fighter is listed as Fighter A of Fighter B.

Comment: Sure. I think the problem is when I want to query it form a Fighter though. Say I'm showing Brock Lesnar's profile. I want to show his fight history, so any records where his ID value appears in either the `fighter_a_id` or `fighter_b_id` column of the `fights` table, ordered by date descending.

Comment: This is something of a non-answer really (in that it doesn't solve this problem), but I'd consider just fetching Fights than. In other words do: `$this->Fighter->Fight->find('all', array('conditions' => array('OR' => array('fighter_a_id' => $id, 'fighter_b_id' => $id))))`

Comment: [The Book](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1043/hasMany) seems to suggest defining 'finderQuery' with a query fragment that tells Cake how to find your related data. I've rewritten this into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Distilled from conversation under the question, the solution would be this:

Rewrite the $hasMany in your FighterModel to look like:

```
   public $hasMany = array(
      'Fight' => array(
         'className' => 'Fight',
         'finderQuery' => 'SELECT * FROM fights AS Fight WHERE Fight.fighter_a_id = {$__cakeID__$} OR Fight.fighter_b_id = {$__cakeID__$};'
      )
   );
```

Comment: Ah, yes! I remember reading something about that. Thanks. I'll give this a try and report back on how it goes.