# CakePHP table has two relations to another table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am setting up a Real Estate  system using CakePhp 2.x. My problem is I cannot relate my Owner Table(hasMany) to my Deed Table(hasOne and hasOne). I have been following this [Models with two hasOne relations to same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962904/models-with-two-hasone-relations-to-same-table) The first table is Owner has the following columns:

```
id | lastName | firstName | middleName | etc...
```

The second table is Deed has the following columns:

```
id | owner_buyer | owner_seller | etc...
```

In the table Deed the owner_buyer and owner_seller are both Owners, and i can't change both the owner_buyer and owner_seller columns to owner_id. I have statically entered the owner ids for each deed but I am unable to retrieve the owner information.

Here is some additional information:

Deed Model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Deed extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array(
        'OwnerA' => array(
            'className' => 'Owner',
            'foreignKey' => 'owner_buyer'
        ),
        'OwnerB' => array(
            'className' => 'Owner',
            'foreignKey' => 'owner_seller'
        )
    );
}
```

Owner Model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Owner extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Deed' => array(
            'className' => 'Deed',
            'finderQuery' => 'SELECT * FROM deeds AS Deed WHERE Deed.owner_buyer_id = {$__cakeID__$} OR Deed.owner_seller_id = {$__cakeID__$};'
        )
    );
}
```

deedList.ctp

```
...
<td><?php echo $deed['Owner']['owner_buyer']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $deed['Owner']['owner_seller']; ?></td>
...
```

buyer and seller both give me the following Notice:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: Owner
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$deed['Owner']` - There is no association Deed->Owner defined in the question.

Comment: My first comment is still accurate. If you're making up names for the question - don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the notice I think you have problem with the variable $deed.
Could you copy and paste all information about notice?

Moreover, try to add debug($deed) in your ctp file and check if actual structure fits with your expectation.

Salvo